# How to extract the Account's Name according with the total of members?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

For each relevant row I would like to have ColumnC populated with the value from ColumnA repeated (one above the other) in the `C` cell the number of times there are separate (one above the other) entries in the correponding `B` column.

[image: WA10513 Q example]

Is it possible?

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oraLkV6COvk445_Lr2n9Vo5B0h_1O4bNDvOXzsQRqwU/edit#gid=1790482812)

Comment: Why is [tag:regextract] included? What do you mean by "to become more detailed"? Why there are more than one line by cell?

Comment: @pnuts: Congratulations for having your answer accepted. I still think that this question should be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the result you want can be achieved with:

```
=ArrayFormula(left(REPT(A1:A&char(10),len(B1:B)-len(substitute(B1:B,CHAR(10),""))+1),LEN(REPT(A1:A&char(10),len(B1:B)-len(substitute(B1:B,CHAR(10),""))+1))-1))
```

but I have made no attempt to optimise it.

Comment: Wow.. !   It's so great and wonderful.   Hi.. !   pnuts thanks  you are so very pretty kind so much It's work very beautiful and thanks once again to you.

I have a difficult to explain these all talking it with speaks in english. How best you, you could understand my language as well ...

Comment: if you don't mind with pleasure to solve my any problems on another thread on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43345422/how-to-make-a-occurrence-sequence-number-order-with-continuing-from-cell-on-cell  .   Probably you could solve that too with so easy looks like an above ealier you did and fix my problem as well too.

Comment: So What sould I do? Do I should post it back to here?

Comment: Wow.. Well I have just know that if there are so many all rules like that what you've just mentioned.  But I didn't post it (about any problems) yet in here (SE) !   My mistake is make a thriple duplicates that post in the same site (SO) right ?   I have to say so sorry with that and I can't pick it back my questions where was have been there. Meanwhile I correct it that's not about GAS but just formula What I want to do with.